# unexpected string in append() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append a some HTML to a code in jquery, but chrome keeps throwing "unexpected string" at the append function, here's the code :

```
for (var i =0 ;i<resultArray.length;i++){
            $.ajax({url:"getExpenseInfo.php",type:"POST",data : {
            'expenseId' : resultArray[i]["expenseId"]
            },success:function(expense){
                expense = $.parseJSON(expense);
                $("#mainDiv").append("<div class=\"row\">".expense["expenseName"]."</div>");

        }});
    }
```

Comment: As a sidenote, you can do `$("#mainDiv").append( $('<div />', {'class': 'row', text : expense['expenseName']}) );`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're mixing up php and js syntax, string concatenation works with `+` in js and not `.`.

```
$("#mainDiv").append("<div class=\"row\">" + expense["expenseName"] + "</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string concatenation in your append function is a little off. Try something like this:

```js
for (var i =0 ;i<resultArray.length;i++){
            $.ajax({url:"getExpenseInfo.php",type:"POST",data : {
            'expenseId' : resultArray[i]["expenseId"]
            },success:function(expense){
                expense = $.parseJSON(expense);
                $("#mainDiv").append("<div class=\"row\">"+expense[expenseName]+"</div>");

        }});
    }
```